# Laravel 5.2 - Insert value into User column not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I created a simple user registration application:

```
$confirmation_key = str_random(100);
$data = [
    'email' => $post['email'],
    'password' => Crypt::encrypt($post['password']),
    'confirmation_key' => $confirmation_key
];
User::create($data);
```

Of course I added a migration for it:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('confirmed')->default(0);
            $table->string('confirmation_key')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

The user added successfully into the database, but the confirmation key still null, not changing.
**Additional question:** What if i want to add another columns to User table? What i need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure you have added `confirmation_key` into `$fillable` property of `User` model like so:

```
protected $fillable = ['email','password','confirmation_key'];
```

If you want to add another columns you need to create new migration and run it and if you want to make this column fillable you need to add it to `$fillable` property of `User` model.

**EDIT**

If you want to make any column not fillable using `create` of `fill` method you can add it into table and it won't be possible simply to do:

```
User::create($data);
```

in those cases you will need something like this:

```
// here you fill fillable data
$user = new User($data);
// this way you can fill properties that are not fillable
$user->some_not_fillable_property = 'some value';
// now you save it to database
$user->save();
```

Comment: What if the column is not fillable? what can i do with unfillable columns?